# Dual of Day convolution

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

[Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution#InTermsOfCoends) of two V-functors $F, G$ is defined as

$$(F \ast G)(X) = \int^{A,B} \mathbf{C}(A \otimes B, X) \otimes F(A) \otimes G(B).$$

This can be also seen as $F \ast G = \mathsf{Lan}_{\otimes}(F \otimes G)$.

What would be a reasonable dual of this concept?

The second definition hints at something like $\mathsf{Ran}_{(\to)} (F \to G)$ for $(\to)$ the
exponential. However, I do not see how could this be unital, for instance.  What are the options if we want something like a dual of Day convolution and which properties do they satisfy?

Comment: I feel like whatever the answer to this question is, it should end up forming a monoidal structure in which oplax monoidal functors are monoids/comonoids (because standard Day convolution doesn't work for $[C^{op}, D^{op}]$ when it does for $[C, D]$).